# Make NSWindow remain "float" when space changes in swift

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, nspanel

I currently have:

```
    let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: 200, height: 200), styleMask: [.borderless], backing: .buffered, defer: true)
    window.backgroundColor = NSColor.green
    window.level = .floating
        
    window.collectionBehavior = [.stationary, .canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

**Current behaviour:**
When space changes (moving between full screen windows) the window moves relative to the desktop/space .

[image]

**Expected behaviour:**
I want the window to behave much like the notifications window in macOS, where the window "floats" above the screen even when active space changes.

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution here?

Comment: No, don't think there is a way to achieve this.